# A problem on denseness

Tags: real-analysis

Is the set $\{2\pi n \theta (mod) 2\pi : n \in \Bbb N\}$ dense in $[0,2\pi]$ for any irrational $\theta$? What about $\theta$ being rational?

Comment: This is not an answer as such. But in general for fixed real $r$,  sets of the form ${a+ br : a,b \in \mathbb Z , r \in \mathbb R} $ is dense in $\mathbb R$. See Dirichlet's approximation theory in number theory. Hope this helps.

Comment: You can find these in Stein's book: An Introduction to Fourier Analysis. Further more, **Weyl's equidistribution theorem** in chapter four.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\theta$ is irrational. It suffices to show
$$\inf\{2\pi n \theta \mod 2\pi : n \in \mathbb{Z}, (2\pi n \theta \mod 2\pi \neq 0)\} = 0$$
for then we can approximately any number arbitrarily closely by taking multiples of small $2\pi n \theta$. By irrationality of $\theta$, the set over which we are taking the infimum is infinite, so there is a limit point. So let $n_1, n_2$ be such that $2\pi n_1 0 < \theta - 2\pi n_2 \theta < \epsilon$ for arbitrarily small $\epsilon$. Then $0 < 2\pi(n_1 - n_2) \theta < \epsilon$, which proves that the infimum must be zero.

This is not dense when $\theta$ is rational, since the set is finite.

Comment: What is the definition of $a \mod b$ where $b$ is irrational ? I guess division algorithm talks about only integer divisions.